# derivative of a metric in a target space with respect to string coordinates

Tags: string-theory, differential-geometry

By my understanding, in String Theory, you have two metrics: a string metric $\gamma_{ab}$ covering the string's 2D world sheet (of string coordinates $\sigma$ and $\tau$) and the spacetime metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ on the 3+1 world-volume in the target space (with the usual coordinates ($x,y,z,t$)).

Can I write $\nabla_{a}g_{\mu\nu}=0$? I think this should be true because $g_{\mu\nu}$ is based on the coordinates $(x,y,z,t)$ in the target space, and does not explicitly depend on the string coordinates $\sigma,\tau$ of the string worldsheet.

Thank you for any clarification. (Usually $g_{\mu\nu}$ is taken to be the Minkowski, but for the sake of argument, I want to relax that assumption).

Comment: Thinking about this question more, I think that $\nabla_a g_{\mu\nu}=0$. If I notice that $g_{\mu\nu}$ contains no string indices, then $\nabla_a g_{\mu\nu}=\partial_a g_{\mu\nu} = 0$ (where $g_{\mu\nu}$ is treated as a scalar quantity). We still have $g_{\mu\nu}[x(\sigma,\tau)]$, but since $g_{\mu\nu}$ does not explicitly depend on the string coordinates, the partial derivative $\partial_a g_{\mu\nu}=0$. I'm hoping someone who knows more string theory than I do can offer some insight.